# remapping emacs keys using scancodes

Tags: windows, emacs, keyboard-layout

In Emacs 24 in Windows, the "previous buffer" and "next buffer" keys are unhelpfully bound to "XF86Back" and "XF86Forward" which is a bit nonsensical in Windows.

On my Lenovo x220 there are "browser go back" and "browser go forwards" buttons that I'd like to remap. They don't get seen by emacs when I try to use global-set-key though.

If I know the scancode of a key, how can I use it in Emacs?

Comment: Try `C-h c` and then the key you want to bind.  If Emacs actually sees the key, that will tell you what it's called.

Comment: The button doesn't produce anything that emacs can see.

Comment: In that case, you are out of luck. Emacs needs to see the key in order to do something with it.  Try using some other keys (that Emacs does see).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
(setq w32-pass-multimedia-buttons-to-system nil)
(global-set-key (kbd "<browser-forward>") 'next-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "<browser-back>") 'previous-buffer)
```

in your .emacs? Works on linux on my x220